# How to get categories of custom post type in WP-JSON v2 API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to get categories of custom post type but unable to find any solution. [The WP REST API documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/taxonomies/) returns only the categories of blog post.

Custom posts API: https://themographics.com/wordpress/service-providers/wp-json/wp/v2/sp_categories

Categories API: https://themographics.com/wordpress/service-providers/wp-json/wp/v2/categories [returns default categories of blog post type]

Is there any way like 
https://themographics.com/wordpress/service-providers/wp-json/wp/v2/sp_categories/categories

Comment: can you add the code that you use to get them?

Comment: @NarekZakarian i have added links, did not have code yet, wanted to confirm if WordPress support this?

Comment: you can get the custom post type taxonomies with get_terms() function

Comment: I need in WP-JSON API to use in mobile app

Comment: ok I'll write the answer

Answer (score 1):

if someone still looking for a solution:

get all:- https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/your-taxonomy
get single:- https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/your-taxonomy/id
get single by slug:- https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/your-taxonomy?slug=slugname

in my case I used 
https://app.local/wp-json/wp/v2/works-categories
https://app.local/wp-json/wp/v2/works-categories/5
https://app.local/wp-json/wp/v2/works-categories?slug=my-slug-name

source: [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462187/wordpress-rest-api-v2-how-to-list-taxonomy-terms)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
add_action('init', 'json_handler');
function json_handler(){
    $categories = get_terms( 'my_cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    if( ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
        // encode the $categories array as json
        print_r( json_encode( $categories ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: this will push all data to json, than you can create the url by yourself